# Facebook Marketing API: addind Page Scoped User IDs in custom audience

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In this topic https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api in part "Custom Audiences from CRM Data" mentioned that I can use Page Scoped User IDs to create custom audience.
What schema type I must specify to use PSIDs? Is it possible now from API?

Comment: My guess would be simply FB_USER_ID ... https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Object/Fields/CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields.php doesn’t list anything other fields related to a Facebook id, and I would suppose that Facebook itself is able to figure out whether a passed id is an app- or page-scoped one.

Comment: @CBroe Hi, thank you, but to use the page scope user id, we need to specify page_id. But the documentation does not describe where in payload specify page_id.

Comment: _“but to use the page scope user id, we need to specify page_id”_ - where does it say that?

Comment: @CBroe because when you do it through facebook ads manager interface, you need to choose page_ids to select users.

Comment: So what, you are not using the interface here. Have you _tried_ it via API and gotten an error message in that regard?

Comment: @CBroe and for app-scoped ids we need to specify app_ids in payload in API. So similarly I think we need to specify page_ids for page-scoped one.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried it via API and what I got: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071822/facebook-api-marketing-issues-with-creating-custom-audience

Comment: That other question is about app-scoped ids, what does that have to do with page-scoped ids?

Comment: It is uncorrect question. Ids are page-scoped. I have tried [APPUID] and UID schemas for them. But result is like in that question

Comment: @CBroe may be it is needed page access token?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use this format when you post the the /user endpoint of a custom audience:

```
{
    payload: {
        schema: ["PAGEUID"],
        is_raw: true,
        page_ids: ["323209841097806"],
        data: [
            ["10208379178770401"],
            ["10208379178770402"],
            ["10208379178770403"],
            ["10208379178770404"],
            ["10208379178770405"]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This work for me. Remark: PSID in "data" should separate each into an array.